# Understanding self.[]

Tags: ruby

- In Java, `this` is this class.
- In Ruby, `self` is this class.

What does this do:

```
self.[] someparameter
```

as in:

```
ALLDATA=YAML.loadFile(somefilenamae)
```

In yml file, we can assume there are key plus values (Japan: Japanese language).

```
def self.[] Japan
  ALLDATA
end
```

Is this a default method that comes with Ruby?

Comment: you can write as `def self.[] name = 'Japan'`

Comment: I edited to try to make sense of the question as much as possible, but even after the edit, the whole text is gibberish. It is just a chunk of non-sense.

Comment: @sawa let it be.. don't need to put any more efforts. OP should do it.

Comment: `def self.[] Japan; ALLDATA; end` is not valid ruby.

Answer (score 4):

`def self.foo` defines a class method, so `def self.[]` defines the static method `[]`.

So

```
class MyClass
  def self.[]
    puts 'asdf'
  end
end
```

will allow you to do

```
MyClass[] #=> 'asdf'
```

Comment: What is *static* method in Ruby ?

Comment: Ruby has no static methods, it's a Class method

Comment: I know.. my comment is to answerer.. :-)

Comment: Sorry for the gibberish thing! Thanks for your effort and help- Sawa!

Comment: @user3055964 If this answer solved your problem, you can accept it as the correct answer.